# Protobuf.net How to use the Any data type?

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I have seen example *.proto files where a `google.protobuf.Any` data type is used. E.g. from the [Eclipse Tahu Sparkplug Version B](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eclipse/tahu/master/sparkplug_b/sparkplug_b_c_sharp.proto) specification where there is something like:

```proto
message Row {
    repeated DataSetValue elements  = 1;
    repeated google.protobuf.Any details = 2;
}
```

When I use the converter from https://protogen.marcgravell.com/, I get an example message in C# where (of course) the type `Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes.Any` is used. The question is now: Is there an equivalent for `protobuf.net` or if not a workaround I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excellent question. I've been meaning to address this area for ages. The answer is a simple "no, I haven't even looked at it". I'd be happy to do so, but reality is that I have limited time and need to prioritise effort on features people are asking for. "Any" is something I've heard basically no noise about, until today. If you have a genuine use case for it, we can probably look. GitHub or email may be a better place to explore it, unless you're happy to handle it simply via `byte[]` and your own code.

Comment: I guess that's fine for now, the use of a byte array should do it in my case. By the way, nice work with your gRPC implementation.